# RuntimeError: Expected object of device type cuda but got device type cpu for argument #1 'self' in call to _th_index_select

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

Can someone kindly help me trace the root of the following error? I don't understand where the switching between GPU and CPU is taking place as from the beginning I have instructed collab to use GPU.
Also following the error stack trace, it points to labels, what could be potentially wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Expected Cuda Type Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to take a look at this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5cngxo4mIg&list=PLZbbT5o_s2xrfNyHZsM6ufI0iZENK9xgG) series to understand how pytorch works.

For your issue specifically I think you'll find your answer in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bs1mdHZiAS8&list=PLZbbT5o_s2xrfNyHZsM6ufI0iZENK9xgG&index=35)

The idea is that you need to specify that you want to place your data and your model on your GPU. Using the method `.to(device)`, device being either cuda if your GPU is available otherwise your cpu, and you need to do the same for your data.

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model.to(device)
```

You also need to do it your data, I assume you have a for loop to iterate over your batch so you could do it like:

```
    for batch in train_loader:
        ***
        x, y = batch[0].to(device), batch[1].to(device)
        ***
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. All this time I was using model.cuda() and I replaced it by model.to(device) and phew I can train my model now. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Comment: I am already using `.to(device)` for both my model and input but still I am getting this error.

Comment: If your model and batches are .to(device) without more context it is hard to say where it can come from, if you had a piece of code or a repo so i can check it would help :)